# Please welcome your newest pro tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. I have some sad news and some happy news. The sad news (for you guys, at least) is that your long-time moderator Tim Bezhashvyly has stepped down from his post here to pursue another project.

Fortunately for you, a great new pro tem mod is taking his place:

[image: Marius]

Most of you probably already recognize Marius, since he's the top user by reputation on the site. What you may not know is that he's been actively participating in community moderation for a long time now, by regularly casting useful flags and votes, and just generally helping the system work the way it's supposed to. Without further ado, please join me in wishing Tim well on his next adventure and welcoming Marius to your moderator team!

Comment: Congrats buddy!

Comment: Congrats @marius you deserve this.

Comment: Congrats Marius, well deserved! And thanks for your work, Tim!

Comment: Thank you all .

Comment: well deserved. Congrats!

Comment: Congratulation Marius!

Comment: Gratz Marius, great choice for a moderator!

Comment: Congrates Marius, always seem to be the one to save the day when i get stuck!!

Comment: Congratulations! And thanks for all your help to date!

Comment: Congratulation Marius! Thanks for your valuable contributions!

Comment: Congratulation Great Teacher :-)

Comment: Success Tim! and welcome Marius!

Comment: Congrats buddy! You've more than put in the effort to deserve this. cc/@Marius

Comment: Congratulation Marius!

Answer (score 14):

Thank you all for the warm welcome and the support.
And thanks to Tim for nominating me for moderator and specially for all the hard work he has put into keeping this website clean until now. And good luck in your next project.
I hope I can fill his shoes or at least come close.

Comment: Congratulations! Definitely deserve it & am sure we're in some very good hands now. Keep up the good work & don't forget to try and have a little fun in-between ;-)

Comment: Hail Marius! [dont let the godly powers over ban and block go to your head]

Comment: @easymoden00b. Don't tell me what to do or not to do or I will ban you :)

Comment: @Marius ***grovelling intensifies***

Answer (score 7):

Congrats Marius :) Nobody deserves it more... nicely done. Now if we could get all three of the pro tems actually moderating on a regular basis we'd be GOLD :)

Answer (score 2):

congratulations marius! You deserved it. You have saved me more than once with magento issues. Congrats and Thanks once again.